# Why does $\lim_{k \to \infty}\psi(k)$ diverge?

Tags: gamma-function, digamma-function

This question is motivated by the fact that 
$$\psi(k)+\gamma=H_{k-1}$$
This, of course, implies that 
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\psi(k)+\gamma = \lim_{k \to \infty}H_{k-1}$$
Since $H_k$ diverges, it follows that $\psi(k+1)$ should also diverge. But $\psi(k)=\frac{\Gamma'(k)}{\Gamma(k)}$. It is intuitive that $\Gamma'(k)<\Gamma(k)$ since the derivative of a function shouldn't grow faster than the function itself, so the denominator would grow faster than the numerator, implying that the limit does not diverge. What is the particular reason that the digamma function diverges?

Comment: As you see from the first part, the end of your question is contradicted by $\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$

Comment: $$$f(x)=e^{x^2}<2xe^{x^2}=f'(x)$$ when $x$ is "large enough" (i.e. $x >\frac{1}{2}$)

Comment: This simply means that your intuition should be corrected. What about $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}\quad\text{as}\quad x\to1^-$$ or $$f(x)=e^{x^2}\quad\text{as}\quad x\to\infty$$? Overall, $f'(x)/f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)$ for a positive function $f(x)$ shows that you can assume any behavior for the ratio.

Comment: @SangchulLee That is very true I didn't consider that! Nonetheless, I would still like to know why the digamma function itself diverges.

Comment: @TyJensen $H_{k-1}>\ln(k)$, so $\psi(k)>\ln(k)-\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\psi(n)=H_{n-1}+\gamma=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}+\gamma$$
Notice that $\ln(1+x)  <x, x>0$, let $x=1/k$, so 
$$\frac{1}{k} > \ln(k+1)- \ln k$$ Now we can do telescopic summing
Then 
$$H_{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}>\ln n$$
So when $n\rightarrow \infty$ $H_{n-1}$ and hence $\psi(n)$ diverge.

Answer (score 0):

What's convincing here depends on your precise definitions and what detailed facts about the gamma function you are comfortable with.  Perhaps this argument
will suit you.

If $\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x)$ were bounded above by $C$ for all $x$ sufficiently large, we would have, for some $A>0$ that $\log\Gamma(x)< A+Cx$ for all $x$ sufficiently large, that is, $\Gamma(x)<\exp(A+Cx)$ for all sufficiently large $x$.  But the well known identity $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ implies that $\Gamma$ grows faster than this.